# Using ARRAYFORMULA with OFFSET where the array should be the offset_rows not the cell_reference

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a `table` that connects serial numbers to items (e.g. 1 - Orange, 2 - Apple, 3 - Banana)
In col `A` I have a list of serial numbers and in col `B` I want each to fetch the relevant item. 
Example, 
col `A`: 2,1,3,1
col `B` should show: Apple,Orange,Banana,Orange

col `A` updates automatically so I need the function in `B` to auto update as well. I'm trying to use the `ARRAYFORMULA` function where the cell range is fixed (the table linking # to items) and where the array should run on the `offset_rows`
The formula should look something like:
`=arrayformula('Table',A1:A,0)`
but it doesn't work. It seems as if the array can only be on the cell range (the Table) and not on the `offset_rows` (A1:a). 
Can I use the arrayformula that way? If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP should work instead.  Try this formula in cell B1:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,Table,2,0)))`

I set up an example sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r8jqUo5tY0s4K3Bhxxstn2__sdtMtiaeMO29ik9XUuw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Works great, thanks!
quick questions:
1 - the iferror is used to get rid of the Blank values, right?
2 - Did Vlookup worked where offset didn't because of the location of the "Range"?

Comment: right, the IFERROR is just there to hide the error messages returned by the blank rows.  I wasn't sure what the original formula was trying to do as the arrayformula will not do a lookup on its own.  So VLOOKUP needs to be included as an 'instruction' for the arrayformula.